# Robust Multivariate Polynomial Regression in Python

Tags: python, r, regression

Is there an easy way to do a multivariate robust polynomial regression in Python? E.g.

```
y = a + bx_1 + cx_2 + dx_1x_2 + ex_1^2 + fx_2^2
```

and possibly higher degree terms, where `a,b,c,d,e,f` are constants and the `x_i` are the dependent variables (there could be more than 2).

I have a set of data plagued by outliers, so the normality assumption does not hold. I have not much knowledge of regressions, but I've found that there are 'robust' methods to deal with this problem. Unfortunately I have not been able to find an easy way to do this in Python, without having to code the entire method. Have I overlooked something? Or should I maybe use another more suited language, such as R? (Since I don't know anything of R, and this is part of a larger problem which I've coded in Python, I would rather do it in Python. But maybe learning R is more efficient than trying to do this kind of stuff in Python.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: robust linear models are available in statsmodels, see [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/examples/generated/example_rlm.html)

Comment: I had already seen that one, but it seems to me that it only does regressions of the type y = a + bx_1 + cx_2 + dx_3 + ... . Or is there a way to include higher degree and mixed terms?

Comment: How about numpy.polyfit? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html

Comment: In polyfit it's easy to do a regression on a polynomial, however, only with one dependent variable. What I have done in a case with two dependent variables, is to use polyfit to find coefficients, and then do a polyfit regression on the coefficients. This works all right, but it gets a bit tedious and probably inefficient to do it with 3+ dependent variables.

Comment: Also polyfit is not robust...

Answer (score 2):

R is very well suited for this, and there are libraries that let you talk to R from Python, like RPy2

http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html

And here is a tutorial on robust regression with R:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/rreg.htm

Comment: What kind of function should I look out for to do the polynomial regression in Rpy (rather than only a constant and terms of degree 1)? And is there a one-to-one correspondence to Rpy and R?

Comment: You would probably use the rlm (robust linear model) from the MASS package. Polynomial regression is just the predictors times themselves if I recall from linear regression, I believe the poly function is what you would use in R on the predictors.
RPy2 provides a higher level and a lower lever interface with R, it's basically a wrapper for R, here's an Introduction: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/introduction.html

Comment: If I do this (using RLM and just multiplying the predictors by themselves) I get numerical issues. " Warnings:
[1] The condition number is large, 2.41e+10. This might indicate that there are strong multicollinearity or other numerical problems."

Even if I center the predictors by subtracting the mean, I still get this. Strange that it did work when I used polyfit.... argh!

Comment: @user1162809 That means you have variables that are collinear, essentially, one of them can proxy for the other. Perhaps you need to eliminate some predictors from your model. Given that you're doing polynomials, try eliminating some of the higher order variables, so you can better specify your model.